# Can I hide implementation details of this concept from the end user?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have looked at several similar questions on SO. Maybe I am not grokking the solutions there. In those questions when the return type is `auto` or templated then separating declaration and definition in two different units causes a failure in compilation. This can be solved by explicitly declaring a concrete signature for the function definition. In my case I am not sure how to do that.

My scenario is as below:

```
// api.h
template <typename TImpl>
concept IsAProcessor = requires(TImpl impl)
{
    impl.init();
    impl.process();
    impl.deinit();
};


enum UseCase {
    USECASE1,
    USECASE2
};

template <IsAProcessor TImpl>
void Process(TImpl& impl)
{
    impl.process();
}

class Engine
{
public:
    IsAProcessor auto getInstance(UseCase a);
};
// End - api.h

// api.cpp
#include "api.h"
#include "third_party.h"
IsAProcessor auto Engine::getInstance(UseCase a) {
    switch (UseCase) {
        case USECASE1:
            return UseCase1Impl(); // Defined in third_party.h and satisfies concept requirement.
        case USECASE2:
            return UseCase2Impl();
    }

    
}
// End - api.cpp

// third_party.h
class UseCase1Impl {
public:
    void init(void);
    void process(void);
    void deinit(void);
}
// End - third_party.h

// third_party.cpp
#include "third_party.h"
void UseCase1Impl::init(void) {...};
// and so forth
// End - third_party.cpp

// User code
#include "api.h"

{
    auto en = Engine();
    auto usecase = en.getInstance(UseCase::USECASE1);
    //^^^ cannot be used before it is defined here    
    Process(usecase);
}
```

As I mentioned in the question, it is not desirable to expose UseCase1Impl and UseCase2Impl. How do I get past the error: `function 'getInstance' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined`

Comment: `UseCase1Impl` and `UseCase2Impl` are different types, you can't decide which one to return based on the function parameter UseCase at *runtime*.

Comment: I didn't show it but UseCase1Impl and UseCase2Impl both implement the constraints imposed by the concept.

Comment: @康桓瑋: I can understand why returning UseCase2Impl would fail in this case: https://godbolt.org/z/fh3ebao89 (Lines 48-50)

Comment: Pass the enum as a template parameter instead. Then you can change the returen type based on it. To hide the implementation of a template function you need to explicit ly instatiate it in one TU. You should be able to find example here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of a function is a static property, it can't change based on runtime data.

If you can, lift `UseCase` to a template parameter, and use `if constexpr` to have exactly one active `return` for each instantiation.

```
template<UseCase a>
auto Engine::getInstance() {
    if constexpr (a == USECASE1)
        return UseCase1Impl(); // Defined in third_party.h and satisfies concept requirement.
    if constexpr (a == USECASE2)
        return UseCase2Impl();
}
```

If you can't do that, you will have to find a common type to return.

```
struct IProcessor
{
    virtual ~IProcessor() = default;
    virtual void init() = 0;
    virtual void process() = 0;
    virtual void deinit() = 0;
};

template <IsAProcessor T>
class ProcessorFacade : public IProcessor
{
    T impl;
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    ProcessorFacade(Args&&... args) : impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    void init() final { impl.init(); }
    void process() final { impl.process(); }
    void deinit() final { impl.deinit(); }
};

std::unique_ptr<IProcessor> Engine::getInstance(UseCase a) {
    switch (UseCase) {
        case USECASE1:
            return std::make_unique<ProcessorFacade<UseCase1Impl>>();
        case USECASE2:
            return std::make_unique<ProcessorFacade<UseCase2Impl>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your idea to templatize the method on UseCase. This helped me solve one of the issues that I had. I am still stuck on the issue with the definition being in a different translation unit like I originally posted about. Your post has given me some ideas. Let me try those and get back to you.